# How to reset all keyboard shortcuts in notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, scintilla, code-editor

I have removed the shortcut for SCI_DELETEBACK and as such my backspace key now outputs a backspace character rather than actually deleting characters.

For whatever reason, it's not possible to re-assign this key (probably because they've assumed no-one will be stupid enough to try and change it) so now I'm stuck.

Ideally I'd like to re-assign the backspace key to the SCI_DELETEBACK command but I think resetting the lot would be easier.

Prove me wrong!

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find the `<ScintillaKeys>...</ScintillaKeys>` tag in `./settings/shortcuts.xml`

Delete shortcuts as applicable. The backspace key is ASCII 8.

If you want to remove all of them, use `<ScintillaKeys/>`.

Comment: +1 I have a strange feeling I'll need this soon. Remember to tick your answer once the system lets you :)